# Working out logical address space

Tags: virtual-memory

If I have 2^32 bytes (512 MB) of physical memory, and we assume that each page is 2^10 bytes, how would I work out what the physical and logical address space would be?

No explanation that I can find makes sense to me.

Comment: Which explanations did you find and how _specifically_ do they not make sense to you?

Comment: [This](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41931/size-of-address-spaces-logical-and-physical) explanation has some calculations but I don't know where the person who answered got the `a process can address 2^32 memory locations` figure from.

Comment: The other explanation is from my university class, so I can't post the content here without violating my lecturer's copyright.
In general, I don't understand how certain figures are extrapolated from given variables; i.e. how do you determine the size of memory address, and from that how do you determine how many addresses there can be depending on the total amount of memory available.

Comment: Citing academic material is usually covered under fair use or similar stipulations, depending on your legislation. (Note: Not the same as copy-pasting their slides!) Even if not, rephrase.  Chances are the answer occurs to you while you do so.

Comment: That said, if your professor is your only source, "no explanation I can find" suggests you did more work than you really did. Check out other resources!

Comment: Also: 2^32 is not 512M, it is 4G.  2^29 is 512M.